# Assign sharing reasons from Dynamically from APEX

Tags: apex, sharing

Was wondering if there is way to assign the Sharing Reason aka Rowcause Dynamically. Well tried to implement using this "Schema.MyCustomObject__Share.rowCause.My_Sharing_Reason__c" but here I have to fix the sObject and the reason. Is there anyway to assign them dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign them completely dynamically.

You need to create them from the point and click interface (Setup->Create->Object Name->Apex Sharing Reasons) or via the meta-data api.

```
myObject__share share = new myObject__share();
share.put('RowCause','APIOfMyApexSharingReason__c');
share.put('ParentId','...');
```

Comment: Created One Sharing Reason with Label "Test Reason" and am using the above code only. I am Getting the following error :  Row Cause: bad value for restricted picklist field: Test Reason;getStatusCode=INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST

Comment: Sounds like your entering it with a space in the label. The label should have underscores, or no spaces. _So maybe something like:_ `TestReason__c` or `Test_Reason__c`

Comment: Well sorry forgot to reply, Rowcause should be the API name for the Apex Sharing Reason.